# Открытия приложения VISIO из программы на C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visio

Задача следующая на visual C++. Код программы не требуется! Прочтите внимательно, может кто знает, или укажет, где посмотреть, куда обратиться. Я знаю, как запустить VISIO из программы, но я не знаю, как запустить из программы редактор BASIC (который встроен в VISIO).Все, что я хочу узнать, это код консоли запуска приложения, таким образом, чтобы оно не простозапустилось, а выполнила еще кое-какие команды, в связи с этим и вопрос:
 Требуется из программы (на языке visual C++) запустить приложение VISIO, запустить редактор BASIC, редактор должен отрыть файл (путь известен) с макросом, запустить макрос, закрыть BASIC. В итоге будет открытый VISIO с рисованной схемой для дальнейшего редактирования схемы. Т.е. требуется код консоли, который бы исполнил вышеописанные процессы. Cамма программа генерирует текс макроса, после чего хотелось бы одним кликом сохранить текст макроса и тут же запустить его в BASIC VISIO. Еще раз повторяю, программа готова. Вопрос из области запуск параллельных процессов.
К примеру  WinExec("C:\Project1.exe", SW_SHOW). Запуск Project1.exe, впишу VISIO, запустится VISIO. Все что в кавычках это код консоли, так вот, мне нужен такой код, который не просто запустит визио, а еще выше сказанное

Answer (score 1):

Вряд ли можно решить такие задачи командной строкой, но вероятно это можно сделать при помощи OLE:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309603/ru